# What's the next step to solve $\int x^2 e^{3x} dx$?

Tags: integration

I started this way:

$$u = x^2 \\
du = 2x$$

$$dv = e^{3x} \\
v = \frac{e^{3x}}{3}$$

$$= x^2 \frac{e^{3x}}{3} - \frac{2}{3} \int e^{3x} x dx$$

Do I need to use u-substitution to solve the last integration?

Comment: Try doing integration by parts again.

Comment: A neat trick to integrals like these is diff under the integral sign. Which is a lot easier on book keeping. Unless this is pre university calculus (I did integrals like this back in the day at A level) and continue with integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the last line.  The integral should be:
$$\int xe^{3x}\,dx.$$

The idea from here is to do integration parts again, and you will finally be left with an integral that does not require parts.

Comment: You're right. Thank you